# Geometric inequality by convexity

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be the vertices of a triangle and let $D$ be a point in its interior. We denote the lenghts of the line segments $AD$, $BD$ and $CD$ by $x$, $y$, $z$ respectively. It is to be shown that the sum $x+y+z$ is less than the triangle´s perimeter. I know this questions has been asked before and there are multiple elementary solutions, but I have been trying to prove this using convexity, the maximum having to be assumed on a vertex, but without success. I´d appreciate solutions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: You may find a solution involving convexity here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413592/sum-of-distances-from-triangle-vertices-to-interior-point-is-less-than-perimeter

Comment: @trancelocation Thank you a lot, seeing the answer it was trivial but I just couldn't find it.

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE you are welcome. just don't get discouraged by not seeing a trivial solution. this just happens naturally once in a while. :-)